# SIGSEGV signal not caught during crash

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run a code that will generate a segmentation fault. But the segmentation fault is not generated.

```
int main()
{

char *variable;

strcpy(variable,"hello");

}
```

The program crashes but the message saying that a segmentation violation has occurred is not getting displayed .

Even when I write a signal handler to handle the segmentation fault , the signal is not getting caught.

Do you know why this is occurring ? Is there any chance that the handling of the SIGSEGV signal by the kernel would have been disabled or something...

Thanks,

Comment: If you didn't get any `SIGSEGV` then it means that your program did *not* crash.

Comment: The garbage value in `variable` may point to somewhere writable, and not corrupting stack, so the program runs without crashing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the segmentation fault has come using gcc compiler(Output : Segmentation fault). But if in your case its not coming , try running your binary using strace like strace ./a.out(say). It will show the the system level command executed on the console. May be u will get an idea from this

Answer (score 0):

First, you really should get the habit of compiling with `gcc -Wall` which warns against such mistakes.

And to understand what really is happening, use a debugger like `gdb` to run your code step by step. You might also use `strace` or better `ltrace`  (which would show the argument to `strcpy`).

Then, a possible explanation (just a guess) might be the following:

- your `variable` is uninitialized
- so it keeps the "value" that the register (or stack slot) storing that `variable`  had previously
- `main` is called by `crt0.o` which happens to initialize that location with something meaningful (a valid pointer), perhaps `argv[0]`  of `main`  or some shell environment variable

(You could read more about [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) to understand how `crt0.o` sets the stack)

If you initialize `variable=NULL;`  you'll get a `SIGSEGV`